# C Program unable to create output text file

Tags: c, file, file-io, stdio

A friend of mine needs to use MATLAB for one of his classes, so he called me up (a Computer Science Major) and asked if I could teach him C. I am familiar with C++, so I am also familiar with the general syntax, but had to read up on the IO library for C.

I was creating some simple IO programs to show my friend, but my third program is causing me trouble. When I run the program on my machine using Eclipse (with the CDT) Eclipse's console produces a glitchy output where instead of prompting me for the data, it gets the input and then prints it all at once with FAILURE.

The program is supposed to get a filename from user, create the file, and write to it until the user enters a blank line.

When I compile/run it on my machine via console (g++ files2.c) I am prompted for the data properly, but FAILURE shows up, and there is no output file.

I think the error lies with how I am using the char arrays, since using scanf to get the filename will create a functional file (probably since it ignores whitespace), but not enter the while loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define name_length 20
#define line_size 80

int main() {
  FILE * write_file;                    // pointer to file you will write to
  char filename[name_length];           // variable to hold the name of file
  char string_buffer[line_size];        // buffer to hold your text

  printf("Filename: ");                 // prompt for filename

  fgets(filename, name_length, stdin);  // get filename from user

  if (filename[name_length-1] == '\n')  // if last char in stream is newline,
    {filename[name_length-1] = '\0';}   // remove it

  write_file = fopen(filename, "w");    // create/overwrite file user named

  if (!write_file) {printf("FAILURE");} // failed to create FILE *

  // inform user how to exit
  printf("To exit, enter a blank line (no spaces)\n");

  // while getting input, print to file
  while (fgets(string_buffer, line_size, stdin) != NULL) {
    fputs(string_buffer, write_file);
    if (string_buffer[0] == '\n') {break;}
  }

  fclose(write_file);
  return 0;
}
```

How should I go about fixing the program? I have found next to nothing on user-terminated input being written to file.

Now if you will excuse me, I have a couple of files to delete off of my University's UNIX server, and I cannot specify them by name since they were created with convoluted filenames...

EDIT------

Like I said, I was able to use

```
scanf("%s", filename);
```

to get a working filename (without the newline char). But regardless of if I use scanf or fgets for my while loop, if I use them in conjunction with scanf for the filename, I am not able to write anything to file, as it does not enter the while loop.

How should I restructure my writing to file and my while loop?

Comment: What's `errno` set to after the `fopen()` fails?

Comment: do you have write permissions? I ask because you say your University's server, and those types of setups usually have strict permissions

Comment: @Sithregal It's probably worth trying to avoid mixing fgets and scanf. If you change the newline check to:

    if (filename[strlen(filename)-1] == '\n')
      {filename[strlen(filename)-1] = '\0';}

it seems to work for me but you're also writing the last, empty line to the file. You probably would be better using a do...while loop rather than a while one, it's a very underused structure in my experience :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines seem to be incorrect:

```
if (filename[name_length-1] == '\n')    // if last char in stream is newline,
    {filename[name_length-1] = '\0';}   // remove it
```

You verify the name_length - 1 character,, which is 19 in your case without any regard of the introduced filename's length. So if your file name's length is less then 18 you won't replace the '\n' character at the end of your string. Obviously the file name can't contain '\n' character.

You need to get the size of you file name first with strlen() as an example.

```
if (filename[strlen(filename) - 1] == '\n')
{
    filename[strlen(filename) - 1] = '\0';
}
```

(Don't forget to include the string.h header)

I hope I was able to help with my weak english.

Answer (score 3):

Your check for the newline is wrong; you're looking at the last character in filename but it may be before that if the user enters a filename that's shorter than the maximum. You're then trying to open a file that has a newline in it's name.